# Haskell splitAt function using Error Handler

Tags: haskell

I am attempting to write a function in Haskell that splits a list into two at the point after the nth element.

I have the following code so far:

```
data Err e = Bad|Good e

splitAt:: Int -> [a] -> Err(([a],[a]))
splitAt 0 zs = Good(([], zs))
splitAt n _ = Bad
```

I am not sure how to apply the error message to the following case:

```
splitAt n (z:zs) | n > 0 = (z:zs', zs'') where (zs', zs'') = split (n-1) zs
```

The function should also return the error message "Bad" if the number is greater than the length of the list, or if the number is negative. E.g

```
splitAt 6 [1,2,3,] = Bad
splitAt (-3) [1,2,3] = Bad
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why use `Err`? That's what `Maybe` is for, and you have a whole library to help you if you use it.

Comment: I'm new to Haskell and wish to practice using polymorphic types

Comment: Oh, ok. Just know your Err type is a minimal version of Haskell's Maybe. In "real code" opt to use Maybe instead.

Comment: You want to return an error when n is negative and when n is bigger than the lenght of the array, right? So you can star considering those cases

Answer (score 0):

This is how i would implement this. The Functor instance is for convenience to avoid something like `case ... of` in the `splitAt` function, and would work exactly the same with `Maybe`. Since your version of `splitAt` can return different values you can't simply modify the example with the `where` you posted since modifying the pattern match to something like `Good (zs',zs'') = ...` would raise an exception in case a `Bad` was returned and vice versa.

```
  data Err e = Bad|Good e deriving (Eq, Show)

  instance Functor Err where
    fmap _ Bad      = Bad
    fmap f (Good a) = Good (f a)

  splitAt' 0 zs = Good ([],zs)
  splitAt' n [] = Bad
  splitAt' n (z:zs) 
    | n > 0     = fmap (\(zs',zs'') -> (z:zs',zs'')) (splitAt' (n-1) zs)
    | otherwise = Bad
```

I hope this helps. Feel free to ask if something is unclear.